# How to make my webpage automatically show the mobile view?

Tags: html, css, web, formatting

To view the page according to the mobile resolution,  "the user should enable the desktop version" on the mobile browser. If the "desktop version button" of the mobile browser is not enabled, it shows according to the mobile resolution. So it works oppositely than it is supposed to work. What would cause this? I couldn't find the causes of this misbehavior.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my html file already had this without .0 at the end, I added how you shared the snippet here but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Then perhaps you should show a **minimum reproducible** example. Because this line is enough to make a webpage mobile-friendly.

Comment: Yes the resolution works the issue is on the mobile browser, when I first open the webpage it shows the desktop version. When I enable the desktop view  (show desktop view button from hamburger menu of the browser) it shows the mobile version. This is a logical error where I couldn't find why and what is causing, It should first show the mobile view (without enabling the desktop view) and optionally if I click the desktop view button,  it should show the desktop version, but it works totally in the opposite way.

Comment: Perhaps it's the browser/phone itself at fault, not the code of the page.

Comment: I was reviewing the index file and noticed that it has this
<!DOCTYPE html>
<g="en">
    <head>

Then I checked the definition of <g= on (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g), and it says, it's Scalable Vector Graphic.

Can it be because of that?